# Error while subscribing page to Facebook App - Code 200 (Insufficient Permission)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm attempting to set up a way to retrieve Facebook Lead Ads as per instructions given here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/guides/lead-ads/retrieving/

However on subscribing a page to the App, I'm getting the following error on printing the response:

```
code: 200
error_subcode: 1373034
error_user_msg: "You do not have the necessary permission for the 
specified Page to perform the requested action."
error_user_title: "Insufficient Permission"
fbtrace_id: "CLbnoml6VX1"
is_transient: false
message: "Permissions error"
type: "OAuthException"
```

Here is the segment of code used to subscribe the app:

```
function subscribeApp(page_id, page_access_token) {
 console.log('Page Access Token:'+page_access_token);
 console.log('Subscribed Page to FB Leads Live Update. Page ID: ' + page_id); 
 FB.api('/' + page_id + '/subscribed_apps', 
 'post',
 {access_token: page_access_token, subscribed_fields: 'leadgen'},
 function(response)
 {console.log('Successfully subscribed page', response);
 });

}
```

I suspect that the page being subscribed is in question here (as the error states), and must be set accordingly to be subscribed to my app. I should state that the page is already subscribed to another app, and I'm using this page for testing purposes on my second FB App for another web application. Any insight would be appreciated!

Comment: Adding a "me too" The weird part for me is that I have done this with dozens of page with no issue. Only one page is displaying this error.

Comment: FYI, my client just confirmed that the page was already subscribed to another leads app! We are trying to disconnect and see if we can reconnect to my app. You might want to investigate that also

Answer (score 0):

Same situation.

Your assumption is correct. You can't have 2 apps attached to capture leads.

Once the other app is disconnected and enough time has passed (No explanation of how long), permissions will be set correctly